# IndexError: string index out of range error

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I am trying to make a map using [`pygame`](http://pygame.org/hifi.html), but I am getting the 
`IndexError: string index out of range` 
error every time I launch the program.

This is the line getting the error: `return self.data[y][x]` in

```py
def__getitem__(self, xy):
    x = xy[0]
    y = xy[1]
    return self.data[y][x]
```

It worked when I had my map defined as

```py
hallway_entrance_lilbrary =\
["xxxxx...........xxxxx",
 "xxxxx...........xxxxx",
 "xxxxx...........xxxxx",
 "xxxxx...........xxxxx",
 "xxxxx...........xxxxx",
 "xxxxx...........xxxxx",
 "xxxxx...........xxxxx",
 "xxxxx...........xxxxx",
 "xxxxx...........xxxxx",
 "xxxxx...........xxxxx",
 "xxxxx...........xxxxx",
 "xxxxx...........xxxxx",
 "xxxxx...........xxxxx",
 "xxxxx...........xxxxx",
 "xxxxx...........xxxxx",
 "xxxxx.....s.....xxxxx",]
```

where `x` is a wall, `.` is a floor tile and `s` is the starting square.

The error started showing up when I changed the map to

```py
hallway_entrance_lilbrary =\
["xxxxxxx...xxxxxxx"
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xx....x...x....x",
 "xxxxxxx.s.xxxxxx",]
```

I tried making the new map shorter, so its length is comparable to the first one, but the error is still generated.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## Incorrect Syntax

I looks like you are missing a comma on the first line of the seconds example.

> ```py
> hallway_entrance_lilbrary =\
> ["xxxxxxx...xxxxxxx" # <--- no comma?
>  "xx....x...x....x",
>  ...
> ```